# Laravel eloquent : Model attribute with conditional concatenation

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, concatenation

I have a table (say myreferencetable) with name list as..say :

```
id    |    name   |   abbrv
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1     | ABCDEF    | abc
2     | TestState |
3     | UVWXYZ    | xyz
```

In my model I have created an attribute for the model :

```
protected $appends = [
        'full_name'
    ];
```

Now,
I want to query DB such that I get the details as:

```
[
 { 
   "name" : ABCDEF
   "full_name" : ABCDEF (abc)
 },
 {
   "name" : TestState,
   "full_name" : TestState
 },
 {
   "name" : UVWXYZ,
   "full_name" : UVWXYZ (xyz)
 }
]
```

i.e. concatenation of strings :

- < name >   //mandatory
- ( < abbrv > )  //if not null

Now, I have my query as :

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {

        return  MyReferenceTable::select(DB::raw('concat(name," (", abbrv, ")")'));
    }
```

But it returns :

```
[
 { 
   "name" : ABCDEF
   "full_name" : {}
 },
 {
   "name" : TestState,
   "full_name" : {}
 },
 {
   "name" : UVWXYZ(xyz)
   "full_name" : {}
 }
]
```

> > I need to return name + ["(abbrv)"]    // where [value] = if not null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->name . ($this->abbrv ? ' (' . $this->abbrv . ')' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    if( ! $this->abbrv)
       return $this->name;

    return sprintf('%s (%s)', $this->name, $this->abbrv);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for :

```
 public function getFullNameAttribute()
        {
            return trim($this->name . (is_null($this->abbrv)? ""  : " (" . $this->abbrv . ")"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (ab)use the `NULL`-handling differences between the `CONCAT()` function and the concatenation operator `||`, i.e.:

```
CONCAT(name, ' (' || abbrv || ')')
```

should do the trick.